# caffe loss does not seem to decrease

Tags: caffe

Some of my parameters

```
base_lr: 0.04
max_iter: 170000
lr_policy: "poly"
batch_size = 8
iter_size =16
```

this is how the training process looks until now:

[image: The Loss seems stagnant]

The Loss here seems stagnant, is there a problem here or this normal?

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to lower the base learning rate by a factor of 10 before resuming training from a solverstate snapshot.

To achieve this same solution automatically, you can set the "gamma" and "stepsize" parameters in your solver.prototxt:

```
base_lr: 0.04
stepsize:10000
gamma:0.1
max_iter: 170000
lr_policy: "poly"
batch_size = 8
iter_size =16
```

This will reduce your base_lr by a factor of 10 every 10,000 iterations.

Please note, it is normal for loss to fluctuate between values, and even hover around a constant value before making a dip. This could be the cause of your issue, I would suggest training well beyond 1800 iterations before falling back on the above implementation. Look up graphs of caffe train loss logs.

Additionally, please direct all future questions to the [caffe mailing group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/caffe-users). This serves as a central location for all caffe questions and solutions.

I struggled with this myself and didn't find solutions anywhere before I figured it out. Hope what worked for me will work for you!

Comment: note that lr_policy step does not reduce learning rate every n iterations, but only once. To make several steps you need to use miltistep policy

Comment: I tried directing my questions to the caffe group but the response rate is too low,either the questions dont get answered or they get answered too late.anyway thanks for the answer